# SQL Server query for date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose if my web service has parameter `year` with value `201718` as string. Then in my query, I want to find something in between `01-04-2017` and `31-03-2018`. The date is a `datetime` in the database. In my query I will use something like this

```
select * 
from table 
where date >= '01-04-2017' and date <= '31-03-18'
```

How should I change the format to accept date as '31-03-18'?

Comment: perhaps you should reformat the '31-03-18' before using it in the query. So that it is consistent with the '01-04-2017'  format. That way you are using the one format in your queries which should work just fine for your datetime sql field.

Comment: Thanks.I got your idea.

Comment: You should put your dates into the proper datatype and use those, so to avoid these 'format' shenanigans. If you really have to use strings, I'd really recommend you doing them all in the yyyy-MM-dd format to avoid locale format conversion errors.

Answer (score 1):

When representing a date using strings in SQL Server, it's best to use `yyyyMMdd`.
For datetime values, it's best to use `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.
The reason for this is that SQL Server will always treat these formats the same way, regardless of local settings of the server.
However, working with string representations of date/datetime is still a bad idea.

So suppose you have a stored procedure that will get the `Years` as string, what you want to do is to get date values from this string. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_SelectByYears)
(
    @Years as char(6)
)

AS 

DECLARE @DateFrom date, @DateTo date;

SELECT @DateFrom = DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(LEFT(@Years, 4) as int), 4, 1),
       @DateTo = DATEFROMPARTS(CAST(LEFT(@Years, 2) + RIGHT(@Years, 2) as int), 3, 31)

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date >= @DateFrom and date <= @DateTo

GO
```

Please note that `datefromparts` was introduced in 2012 version, so if you are working on an older version you need to replace it with `cast`:

```
SELECT @DateFrom = CAST(LEFT(@Years, 4) + '0401' as date),
       @DateTo = CAST(LEFT(@Years, 2) + RIGHT(@Years, 2) +'0331' as date)
```